# (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on updating sql table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, updatecommand

I'm trying to update a field in a table of the database when I keep getting the following error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Code:

```
    public void WILF(string whatIsPlaying)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("WatchedLast", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", whatIsPlaying);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", Variables.UserId);
            con.Open();
            sda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

and here is my store procedure (in case if its needed)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE WatchedLast

@a nvarchar(30),
@b uniqueidentifier

As

BEGIN
   UPDATE aspnet_Membership
   SET WILO = @a
   WHERE (UserId = @b)
END
```

I went through step by step debuging to see if the variables (whatIsPlaying and Variables.UserId) are null, but they are not. the values are set in them. I keep getting the error on

```
sda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You may want to take a look at [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It will allow you to generate Update and other commands from SelectCommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the exception because you never specify an `UpdateCommand`.  The constructor for `SqlDataAdapter` is only setting the `SelectCommand`.

Also, I don't see a need for `SqlDataAdapter` here.  I would just use `SqlCommand`:

```
public void WILF(string whatIsPlaying)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "WatchedLast";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", whatIsPlaying);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", Variables.UserId);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter is not needed ?? can you show me how its done without it ? and btw,thanks for the reply.

Comment: @alinem `SelectCommand` is of type `SqlCommand`.  So you're really already using one.  Anyways, see edited answer.

Comment: there was a bit of hiccup but i got it goin...thank you for the help